# Top border of input turns black when background image used in element; how can I turn off?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to recreate the interface of the google home page (minus functionality of course). I've inserted the little mic picture into the searchbar using `background-image` in CSS. But when I do that, the top portion of the border becomes noticeably darker, and I can't change the color when I edit the class.

I'm very new to using the `background-image` property so maybe there's something obvious I'm overlooking. Here's snippets of the relevant code.

CSS

```
.searchBar{
    width:700px;
    height:40px;

    font-family: arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:18px;

    background-image:url(googleMic.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 670px 9px; 
    background-size: 2.5%;

}
```

HTML

```
<center>        
            <img class="googleImg" src="googleLogo.png" alt="google logo">
            <div>
                <input class="searchBar" type="text" name="searchBar">
            </div>
            <span>Google Search</span>
            <span>I'm Feeling Lucky</span>              
</center>
```

[image: With background image]

[image: Without background image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always add `border: 1px solid;` to your `.searchBar` CSS styling:

```css
.searchBar {
    width:700px;
    height:40px;

    font-family: arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:18px;

    background-image:url(googleMic.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 670px 9px; 
    background-size: 2.5%;
    border: 1px solid;

}
```

```html
<center>        
            <img class="googleImg" src="googleLogo.png" alt="google logo">
            <div>
                <input class="searchBar" type="text" name="searchBar">
            </div>
            <span>Google Search</span>
            <span>I'm Feeling Lucky</span>              
</center>
```